# Walking through stack frames - where to stop?

Tags: windows, x86, stack-trace, callstack

In a vectored exception handler I'm walking through the stack frames like this (in a 32-bit process, assuming there's no FPO):

```
unsigned int *nextFrame;
unsigned int returnAddress;
__asm mov [nextFrame], ebp
while (!IsBadReadPtr(nextFrame, 8))
{
  nextFrame = (unsigned int *)*nextFrame;
  returnAddress = *(nextFrame + 1);
}
```

However, `IsBadReadPtr` seems not good enough stop condition, because after several iterations I get access violation at `*(nextFrame + 1)`.

What would be the correct condition?

**Update**: it turns out that `IsBadReadPtr` raises (and handles) an exception, and thus can't be used in VEH at all.

**Update2** finally, I try to use some "heuristic" to detect where the frames end: I compare a current frame-pointer with the previous one, and break the loop if the difference doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: Possibly related, and definitely interesting either way: [IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx)

Comment: @delnan thanks, it's interesting.

Comment: If the code crashes, then it means that your frame pointer chain is corrupted. (Assuming you remember to stop when the pointer is null.) If the chain is corrupted, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: @Raymond Chen it turns out that in the real life frame pointer chain is never "null terminated".

Comment: A standard frame pointer chain is null terminated. Perhaps there is somebody using a nonstandard frame pointer chain.

Comment: @Raymond Chen I guess it's because of FPO (which I assumed is off, but actually it's on :) )